# Farseer physics engine: save world simulation and load at a later time

Tags: c#, monogame, windows, farseer-physics-engine, velcro-physics-engine

I have created a windows desktop game using monogame and the Velcro (formermy Farseer) Physics engine ([Velcro Physics](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics)).

In this game I would like to the user to be able to save the game and continue at a later time.

When I want to save the Velcro World simulation, do I have to go looping through the bodies and store their data in XML (or similar) and then redo the regular creation again using this data (as I did when I first set up the simulation).. or can we actually serialize the simulation and restore it in some way?

Havent really found much when googling on the subject.. but I'm sure someone has had to have done this before?

Comment: Is the position of everything in your game not enough ? Why would you need every  physic game object value ?

Comment: To continue the simulation I would need at minimum: Body type, Body Size, Friction, Restitution, Position, Rotation, Delta rotation, Speed, Speed delta. I can do all the saving and loading myself, but thought I'd ask if anyone had any tips or ideas really

Comment: body type is the same as the time you create it ... right ? either dynamic or static or something... why would that change through the game

Comment: It would not, but during the game there will be alot of new items added to the simulation, The items it starts with wont be the same that it ends up with.. The new items are created from a object factory so I can save the type they are end recreate them with the same object type and the additional data that I've stored away.

Comment: so you are saying some of the new items are static and some are dynamic ? and you cant guess which is which with any other way ? what kind of game are you making where all new objects have a different speed/rotation/friction/size and you absolutely need to know those values precisely ? a single int for the current level or checkpoint and score points that the user has reached is often enough... because you generally don't go back to previous levels anyway , you know what i mean ?